# access is denied message after create custom user and role in jaspersoft server

Tags: jasper-reports

I created a new role **NORMAL_USER_ROLE** with read only permission and a user **Test_User**.
After that I assigned the **NORMAL_USER_ROLE** to **Test_User** and started the server

When i logged in through this user I am getting error i.e. `"Access is denied`" and `"Please contact your system administrator or log in as a user with permission"`.

Please suggest

Comment: Did you try to change the permission of the root folder of the repository? If not, it should still have it's default value, which is `"No Access"`. In that case you have just to change it on read-only

Comment: I gave the permission to root folder but same error arise.